# Laplace Transform of Lambert W function

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, laplace-transform, lambert-w

Does there exist a Laplace transform of $W(at)$ that can be expressed in terms of elementary functions and the Lambert W function $W(x)$?

If such a transform exists, how is it expressed in terms of $s$, and how is it derived?

A couple properties of the productlog $W(x)$ to note include:
$$
e^{W(x)}=\frac{x}{W(x)}\\
W'(x)=\frac{W(x)}{x\left(1+W(x)\right)}$$
and
$$\int W(ax)=x(W(ax)−1)+\frac{1}{a}e^{W(ax)}+C.$$

Comment: Of course,  the Laplace transform of the Lambert's W function exists. As far as I know, there is no standard mathematic function or combination of a limited number of standard mathematic functions, to express it on a closed form. One have to wait until a new convenient special function be defined and standardized !

Answer (score 6):

I propose to define a new special function, namely LW$(x)$ :
$$\text{LW}(x)=\int_0^\infty W(t)e^{-x\:t}dt$$
where W is the Lamber's W function.

In the futur, if this brand new function becomes standard, if it acquires the honorific status of standard special function, if it spread in the literature with a lot of studies of properties, if it becomes familiar, if it is implemented in mathematical softwares, then you could say :

"The Laplace transform of $\quad \text{W}(ax)\quad$ is $\quad\frac{1}{a}\text{LW}(\frac{s}{a})$."

This would be a typical case of special function emergence, exactly as many special functions emerged :  https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14623310/Safari-on-the-country-of-the-Special-Functions-Safari-au-pays-des-fonctions-speciales

Comment: I seem to remember you from before, you posted a scribd document describing the possibility of a special function that is formed from integrating $x^x$: an idea that has had a long, personal, and somewhat dramatic and somewhat miserable, history with me. You suggested that it should be named a "Sophomore's dream function", as a generalization of the "sophomore's dream" integrals. Right?

Comment: As it turns out that a slightly more general form than the one you presented can actually be used to do this integral, and thus it would be in effect redundant, if one were to use that, to propose an additional one with the first one already proposed. Would you want to see how it works?

Comment: I cannot understand what you are asking for.

Comment: I was pointing out that I found out the integral at hand here is related to something else you (appear to have) worked with earlier.

Comment: For example
$$\text{Laplace transform of }\sin(ax)\:=\:\frac{1}{a}\frac{1}{1+(\frac{s}{a})^2}$$
 because the Laplace transform of $\sin(x)$ is $\frac{1}{1+s^2}$ . You don't want to change of function because $\sin(ax)$ is more general than $\sin(x)$.

Now, on the same manner
$$\text{Laplace transform of W}(x)\:=\:\frac{1}{a}\text{LW}(\frac{s}{a})$$
because the Laplace transform of W$(x)$ is LW$(s)$. Why do you want to change of function because $W(ax)$ is more general than $W(x)$ ?

Comment: @ThoughtOfGod. I am afraid that you don't understand my main answer (a bit humoristic). This is normal if you are not familiar with the general use of  special functions. In this case, the answer to your question is very simple : The Laplace transform of the Lambert's W function exists but you cannot express it on closed form only with the elementary functions that you know.

Comment: @JJaquelin Yes, I wanted W(ax) because it's more general

Comment: @JJaquelin do you have a source of proof that it cannot be expressed? Or is this simply what you believe? Is there any literature at attempts to find this transform with elementary functions that you know of?

Comment: The Laplace transforms  of W$(ax)$ doesn't appear in the extended lists of functions, such as H.Bateman tables etc. Of course, no definitive proof can be given because it could appear if a convenient special function becomes standardized as I already explained several times.

Answer (score 1):

Laplace transform LW(s) of Lambert function W(t) is

$$\frac {1} {2i} \int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}s^{-1-y}\frac {y^{y-1}} {sin\ {\pi y}}\,dy,{\,c \in (0,1)}$$

which is Mellin-Barnes integral. This integral converges for all complex s excluding singularities, of course. I cannot express this integral by known "named" functions.

Other possibility is to calculate integral

$$ \frac {1} {s} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-u} W(\frac {u} {s})\,du$$

i.e. we integrate complex valued function along real *u* > 0. This integral converges for all complex s excluding singularities as well.

Comment: How can you find a form for either of these that may involve something nonelementary, like that of a convergent summation without any closed form?